# Mysql query to check single Datetime value in between two column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

In MySQL, How do I need to check single datetime values in between of two columns?. I tried the below query, but it is not working for particular that time period (12:00:00) series only, I mean from_date and to_date column have 12:00:00, 12:15:00, 12:30:00 and 12:45:00 series time it's not working. What can I do for this?

```
SELECT t2.* , u.userName as userName FROM manageuser as u left join tbl_bookingpayment as t2 on u.userId=t2.user_id WHERE from_time <= '2016-10-05 12:00:00 pm' AND to_time >= '2016-10-05 12:00:00 pm' group by t2.id
```

Comment: It's best to say *why* your program isn't working. Please [edit] your question to be more specific. Also, you are misusing `GROUP BY`; you may want to study how it works and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Like Ollie Jones said, it would help a lot to know how isn't that working and yes, because of `GROUP BY` each of your columns will get an **arbitrary value** from it's group (don't know what value you actually want the columns to get so I don't know what you should do instead)

Answer (score 0):

- We usually use GROUP BY when we want to do some aggregation such as min, max, sum, ... for each group in result.
- I guess values in t2.id are not unique. If so, using GROUP BY without any aggregation in your query means you just want to get only one row for each t2.id (group). And the row of each group is the first row MySQL reachs if there are some rows have the same t2.id value.
- Just remove "group by t2.id", you can see all data.

Comment: I have removed group by t2.id , its not working, Here i have to mentioned my stored  datetime values in table.. 

    from_time                         to_time 

    2016-10-05 12:00:00 pm             2016-10-05 04:10:00 pm

     I want to find this (2016-10-05 12:30:00 pm or 2016-10-05 12:45:00 pm etc ) time in b/w of two column

Comment: Which are the data type of from_time and to_time column? Could you please share the table structure?

Comment: I have to used the Varchar datatype for both columns ,   from_time varchar(300)  and  to_time varchar(300).

Comment: So this is the reason of your issue. I think changing data type of from_time and to_time from varchar to datetime will resolve your problem. Because with varchar data type, MySQL will compare 2 strings together. In this case, "2016-10-05 12:30:00" will be greater than "2016-10-05 04:10:00".

Comment: I already try to change and check datatype is datetime, but its not working..  Refer my inserted values in table is : from_time = "2016-10-05 12:10:00" and to_time="2016-10-05 04:10:00"

Comment: Can you convert "2016-10-05 04:10:00" to "2016-10-05 16:10:00" and remove "pm" from "2016-10-05 12:00:00 pm" in your query.